# Finding image and nucleus of $ f: x \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mapsto (aa^T +bb^T)x \in \mathbb{R}^3 $

Tags: linear-algebra

I got a problem.

> Let $a, b ∈ \mathbb{R}^3$ be two linearly independent nonzero vectors
> in a three-dimensional real space, and let $c ∈ \mathbb{R}^3$ be a
> nonzero vector orthogonal to $a, b$. Find the image and nucleus of the
> linear map:
>
> $$ f: x \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mapsto (aa^T +bb^T)x \in \mathbb{R}^3 $$

I tried to solve this, but what came through my head is:

$$
\operatorname{Im}{f} = \left\{\left(\begin{array}{l}
\left(a_{1}^{2}+b_{1}^{2}\right) x_{1}+\left(a_{1} a_{2}+b_{1} b_{2}\right) x_{2}+\left(a_{1} a_{3}+b_{1} b_{3}\right) x_{3} \\
\left(a_{1} a_{2}+b_{1} b_{2}\right) x_{1}+\left(a_{2}^{2}+b_{2}^{2}\right) x_{2}+\left(a_{2} a_{3}+b_{2} b_{3}\right) x_{3} \\
\left(a_{1} a_{3}+b_{1} b_{3}\right) x_{1}+\left(a_{2} a_{3}+b_{2} b_{3}\right) x_{2}+\left(a_{3}^{2}+b_{3}^{2}\right) x_{3}
\end{array}\right) \, \middle| \, x_1, x_2, x_3 \in \mathbb{R}\right\}
$$

I also do not understand what this question would imply.
Could you give me some hints to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that $f(a)=aa^Ta+bb^Ta=\|a\|^2\cdot a$, $f(b)=aa^Tb+bb^Tb=\|b\|^2\cdot b $ and $f(c)=aa^T c + bb^T c = 0$. Therefore the kernel of $f$ is $c$ and the image of $f$ is $\mathrm{span}\{ a,b \}$.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ and $B$ be matrices, then $rank (A)+rank (B)\geq rank (A+B)$, so the dimension of the image, which is equal to $rank (aa^T+bb^T)$, is no greater than $2$. But you can check that $aa^T+bb^T$ has a sub $2\times2$ matrix with non zero determinant. Thus $dimIm=2\Rightarrow dimker=1$. But $a^Tc=b^Tc=0$ implies that c is in the kernel. Then you can infer what the kernel is.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to see that $c\in \ker f.$

Rewrite $aa^t+bb^t$ as $\begin{bmatrix}a&b&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a^t\\b^t\\c^t\end{bmatrix}\overset{\triangle}{=}AB.$ Since $\mathrm{rank}{B}=3,$ then $\mathrm{rank}(AB)=\mathrm{rank}(A)=2.$ Hence $\mathrm{Im}f=\mathrm{Im}A=A\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}=k_1a+k_2b$ and $\dim \ker AB=1$ which implies $c=\ker f.$